# How do I add a top colored border to a new section of a page using HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to add a red border to the top of a new section of a web page. I currently already have the first section I want done, but need to differentiate each section using a red border. I have provided an image / code to show you what I mean. If anyone can help that would be great!

Note: I am currently using an image from my own folder, so the CSS File url() will not show up for you if you try running the snippet.

```css
/* Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap');

/* Global */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;;
}

/* Banner Section */
.banner {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 55vh;
    background: url(./images/HERO\ 1.jpg) no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
  }
  
  .content {
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .content .title {
    color: #de041c;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 2.2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
  }
  
  .content .subTitle {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  .content .sentence {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assessment</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="banner">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="subTitle">Dolar sit amet aran</div>
            <div class="sentence">Rerum quas delectus non ab eveniet nihil, eaque tempora incidunt blanditiis, molestias
                sit,
                unde id? Tempora eius illo labore officiis quis quae.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-2">
        <section>
            
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: ImageMockup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `border-top` property for your second section

```css
.section-2 {
  border-top: 40px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea why I couldn't think of this solution but I really appreciate it!